# Collapse nested labels by default?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

Some time ago Gmail used to open with each main label 'closed', i.e. with nested labels indicated only by a horizontally-facing triangle. Now, though, Gmail opens with everything open to the max - and since I have a great many nested labels, it is a mess. I have to page down the labels column for maybe a meter before getting to something that starts with e.g. N. This is time-consuming and frustrating. Is there any way to make Gmail open with sub-labels closed by default?

Answer (score 1):

You mention:

> *Some time ago Gmail used to open with each main label 'closed', i.e. with nested labels indicated only by a horizontally-facing triangle.*

**The now default behaviour is to have the main labels at the state (extended/collapsed) as were left by the user.**

This means that if the last time you visited gmail the main labels **you** (the user) left open will still remain open until manually closed (by clicking the little triangle) by **you** (the user).

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered? Did it work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.